# How to put glyphicons in asp gridview asp:buttonField

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, gridview, bootstrap-modal, aspxgridview

I am trying to run this code

```
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Link" ItemStyle-Width="40px" ControlStyle-ForeColor="#cc6600" Text="<i id='h3h' aria-hidden='true' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Billing' data-placement='right' class='glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt'></i>"/>
```

but I would like to change the **ButtonType="Link"** into **ButtonType="Button"** because of some functionality reason, but the glyphicons is not working on a ButtonType="Button", is there any other way to make it work?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this simple one by setting text with *single qoutes*

```
<asp:ButtonField CommandName="Select" HeaderText="SELECT" ShowHeader="True" 
    Text='<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i>' />
```

Comment: so, no need for the ButtonType,? BTW thank you, I'm gonna try it see if it works